# What can be the fault in this haskell code?

Tags: haskell, types, signature

Friendly numbers

- Pairs of numbers for which it is true that the sum of the divisors of one number less than itself is equal to another number and vice versa, we call it friendly numbers. An example is the number pair (220; 284).
- 220: smaller divisors: 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 10 + 11 + 20 + 22 + 44 + 55 + 110 = 284
- 284: smaller divisors: 1 + 2 + 4 + 71 + 142 = 220
- Enter the `areAmicableNumbers` function, which decides a pair of numbers if they are friendly numbers!
- Each of the following test cases must give a `True`:
- `areAmicableNumbers 220 284 == True`
- `not (areAmicableNumbers 220 283) == True`
- `areAmicableNumbers 1184 1210 == True`

```
areAmicableNumbers ::  Integral a => a -> a -> [Bool]

areAmicableNumbers x y = 
   [(sum [k | k <- [1..x], x `mod` k ==0]) == y]  
  && 
   [(sum [i | i <- [1..y], y `mod` i ==0]) == x]
```

```
Error: Homework1.hs:23:26: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `[Bool]'
    * In the first argument of `(&&)', namely
        `[(sum [k | k <- [1 .. x], x `mod` k == 0]) == y]'
      In the expression:
        [(sum [k | k <- [1 .. x], x `mod` k == 0]) == y]
          && [(sum [i | i <- [1 .. y], y `mod` i == 0]) == x]
      In an equation for `areAmicableNumbers':
          areAmicableNumbers x y
            = [(sum [k | k <- [1 .. x], x `mod` k == 0]) == y]
                && [(sum [i | i <- [1 .. y], y `mod` i == 0]) == x]
   |
23 | areAmicableNumbers x y = [(sum [k | k <- [1..x], x `mod` k ==0]) == y] && [(sum [i | i <- [1..y], y `mod` i ==0]) == x]
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Homework1.hs:23:75: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `[Bool]'
    * In the second argument of `(&&)', namely
        `[(sum [i | i <- [1 .. y], y `mod` i == 0]) == x]'
      In the expression:
        [(sum [k | k <- [1 .. x], x `mod` k == 0]) == y]
          && [(sum [i | i <- [1 .. y], y `mod` i == 0]) == x]
      In an equation for `areAmicableNumbers':
          areAmicableNumbers x y
            = [(sum [k | k <- [1 .. x], x `mod` k == 0]) == y]
                && [(sum [i | i <- [1 .. y], y `mod` i == 0]) == x]
   |
23 | areAmicableNumbers x y = [(sum [k | k <- [1..x], x `mod` k ==0]) == y] && [(sum [i | i <- [1..y], y `mod` i ==0]) == x]
   |                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: Why not enter that definition into GHCi, and then use `:t` to find its type?

Comment: I don't know what I have to write after :t .

Comment: As GHCi states when you open it, “:? for help”. This shows: “:type <expr>, show the type of <expr>”. So you want `:type areAmicableNumbers`. (`:t` is an abbreviation for `:type`, which comes in handy when you’re using it frequently.)

Comment: An expression of the form `[a == b]` has type `[Bool]`, list-of-bools. I don't think you want that, so you should amend the code. (The type of the whole function is related but different.)

Comment: when you edited, didn't you notice the triple backticks I put around your code block? didn't you notice their effect? don't you see how utterly unreadable your error message is right now? don't you want to put the triple backticks around it and see if it improves it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how this is working. I just new on this site and I just get to know this site.

Comment: but have you [looked into this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69479166/edit) now? will you now be able to use the triple backticks around your code blocks?

Comment: Oh I didn't know this. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! and kudos for staying engaged. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1==1` has type `Bool`.

`[1==1]` has type `[Bool]`.

`(&&)` expects two arguments of type `Bool`. Instead it finds two arguments of type `[Bool]`. the two types are different. The program is thus rejected.

```
GHCi> :type (&&)
(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool

> :type (&&) :: [Bool] -> [Bool] -> [Bool]

<interactive>:1:1:
    Couldn't match type `Bool' with `[Bool]'
    Expected type: [Bool] -> [Bool] -> [Bool]
      Actual type: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
    In the expression: (&&) :: [Bool] -> [Bool] -> [Bool]
```

The square brackets around your tests are wrong. They shouldn't be there.

```
GHCi> :type [1==1] :: Bool

<interactive>:1:1:
    Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `[Bool]'
    In the expression: [1 == 1] :: Bool

GHCi> :type (1==1)
(1==1) :: Bool
```